# Is integrability metric-dependent?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Does integrability of real functions depend on the metric chosen? Although the Riemann integrability depends on limits, the Darboux integrability depends on the order defined (a function is Darboux integrable if the infimum of all the upper sums is equal to the supremum of all lower sums), since it uses the notion of supremum and infimum. So my question is - if I change the metric defined on the reals, will all standard integrable function will remain integrable with the same values?

EDIT:
Suppose that we change the metric of both the domain and the range. Also, I am asking generally if Riemann integrable can become non-integrable and vice versa. I am talking about finite-interval integrability. Also, a general metric change with no special care about the topology.

Comment: This question is intriguing. However, recall that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique complete ordered field. If you change the order relation on $\mathbb{R}$ in an incompatible way with the usual one, you will probably lose completeness and this may cause troubles...

Comment: I was under the impression that a function was *Riemann* integrable if the supremum of the lower sums was equal to the infimum of the upper sums.

Comment: The Riemann integrability and Darboux integrability are equivalent

Comment: You have to be more specific. For instance, are you changing metric on the domain or on the range of the function or both? Do you want new metric(s) be compatible with the standard topology on ${\mathbb R}$? Furthermore, are you only asking: Does Riemann integrable function remain Riemann integrable after change of metric(s) or, also, does Riemann nonintegrable function remain nonintegrable after the change. Are you looking only at integrals of functions on finite intervals? Etc. Answers will depend heavily on the precise formulation.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Edited.

Comment: To clarify: are you talking about *Lebesgue* integrability (as done in measure theory), or about *Riemann* integrability?

Comment: @AlexM. Riemann integrability

Comment: Riemann integrable functions have to be continuous a.e.. Changing metric regardless of topology can make a continuous function to be discontinuous at every point and, hence, nonintegrable. I suggest you keep the topology on both domain and the range and stick to bounded  functions on closed intervals. Then Riemann integrability is retained provided the change of metric on the domain is absolutely continuous and in the range - continuous.

Comment: Changes in the metric structure of the domain is essentially captured in the notion of [Sieltjes versions of the integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). I am not sure what you mean by changing the metric structure of the range: to even conceive of "summing" or "integrating" you want to use the linear structure of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose you are given the set $\mathbb{R}$ with some metric function $d$, can you write down what you mean by "Riemann integrable" using this new metric?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: That is what I thought too, until thinking about the definition: the Riemann sums stay the same when you change the distance, because in them you use $|x_i - x_{i-1}|$, not $d(x_i, x_{i-1})$. Therefore, nothing changes, because the definition of Riemann integrability does not "see" the underlying topology. The one that would change is that Hausdorff measure (obtained from the metric), hence the Lebesgue integral associated to it. But this is not what the OP asks for.

Comment: @WillieWong A metric can be defined over a set $X$ even if the set has no order. Distance between points has nothing to do with "which point comes first", for example $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ with a metric $d$, I can define Darboux integration using just the order relation over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @AlexM. Riemann sums are not dependent on metric, but Riemann integrability is, since you are taking partitions that bring the Riemann sums "closer and closer" to the integration value. Although equivalent, the Darboux defintions does not use the notion of closeness (as I see it, maybe I am wrong).

Comment: To make @MoisheCohen's comment concrete: let $\phi$ be the function that acts as the identity on the irrationals and negative the identity on the rationals. Then most Riemann integrable functions are not Riemann integrable under the "metric" induced by $\phi$ on the domain. // I feel like this question is not yet very well thought-out and is very much a moving target. For starters, please write down fully what you would conceive as a definition of Riemann and Darboux integrability of a function from the metric space $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$ to $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$.

Comment: @Joshhh: I was thinking only about changing the metric on the domain of $f$, in which case the "closer and closer" thing that you are mentioning does not change. Do you also want to change it on the codomain of $f$?

Comment: @AlexM. Why would you use $|x_i - x_{i-1}|$ and not $d(x_i, x_{i-1})$? (Why do you say it is "the definition"? The definition of what?)

Comment: @WillieWong: The fact that you have an order (compatible with the algebraic operations) on $\Bbb R$ allows you to always resort to it and write $x_i - x_{i-1}$ (without modulus), without the need to use the metric.

Comment: @AlexM. then you are just trivializing the OP's question with your chosen interpretation. You are basically saying that since "stuff are defined relative to this other god-given metric, it doesn't matter if you put a new metric on it since we won't use it anyway." (Incidentally that's why I keep asking the OP to edit the question to provide _his_ definition of Riemann/Darboux integrability so we don't have to have this kind of discussions.)

Comment: @WillieWong: You are partly right: notice, though, that for some mysterious reason you keep coming back to the concept of metric. I am not using a God-given metric, but rather a God-given order. And, indeed, once I am doing this, the metric becomes irrelevant. The answer to the OP's question is much simpler: "it depends". The Riemann integral sits in the overlapping of many integration theories. If you *choose* to view it as an instance of Hausdorff-measure integral, then the change in metric severely impacts your theory. I *chose* not to use the metric. It's about freedom of interpretation.

Comment: @AlexM. that "mysterious reason" that you failed to grasp is staring at you **in the title of the question that was asked**. The OP choose to frame the question as a discussion of metrics. Moishe and I try to engage the OP to figure out what it is meant. You are of course free to ignore the OP and do your own thing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me spell out what I mean by Riemann integral with respect to the metrics $d$ on the range and $\rho$ on the domain of a function, restricting to bounded functions $f$ defined on closed intervals.

Let $P=(x_0<...<x_n)$ denote a partition of $[a,b]$ of mesh $m_\rho(P)$ (defined via the metric $\rho$). For this partition and a choice of sample points $t_i\in [x_{i-1}, x_{i}], t=(t_1,...,t_n)$, define the partial sum
$$
S(f, P, t):= \sum_{i} d(f(t_i), 0) sign(f(t_i)) \rho(x_i, x_{i+1}).
$$
Here $sign(y)= y/|y|$ if $y\ne 0$ and $sign(y)=0$ if $y=0$. Thus, this sum is the sum of "signed areas" of rectangles where the area is defined via the product metric on ${\mathbb R}^2$ defined via the metrics $\rho$ and $d$. Unlike what Alex M. is proposing, this definition is consistent with the more general notions of integration on metric / measure spaces. Riemann himself did not intend to define his integral beyond the realm of Euclidean spaces.

Then the Riemann integral 
$$
\int_{d,\rho, [a,b]} f(x)dx
$$
is defined as the limit (if it exists) 
$$
\lim_{m_\rho(P)\to 0} S(f, P, t).
$$

Now, consider some examples: Take the constant function $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$. Then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$. But if you change the metric on $[0,1]$ by multiplying it by $a>0$ then the integral of the same function becomes $a$. Hence, even in the simplest case, you cannot  hope to retain the values of integrals. Next, let me restrict to bounded functions on closed intervals. Then a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere in $[a,b]$ in the Lebesgue sense. Now, if $h: [a,b]\to [a,b]$ is a homeomorphism (a continuous monotonic function) which carries a Cantor set $C$ of zero Lebesgue measure to a Cantor set of positive Lebesgue measure then $\chi_C$ is Riemann-integrable but not $\chi_C \circ h^{-1}$. Hence, by changing the metric  on $[a,b]$ via the function $h$:
$$
\rho(x,y):= |h^{-1}(x)- h^{-1}(y)|,
$$
does not preserve Riemann-integrability.

If you change the metric on the range while preserving the topology on the range then the notion of continuity does not change, hence, Riemann-integrability is preserved. But changing the metric on the target to, say, the discrete metric, makes every nonconstant continuous function on $[0,1]$ a discontinuous function. Therefore, say, the function $f(x)=x$ becomes discontinuous everywhere and hence, non-integrable.

The bottom line is that you want to retain the topology on the range and make an absolutely continuous change of topology on the domain. Then Riemann integrability is retained (for bounded functions).

Comment: Changing the metric on $[0,1]$ has no influence on the Riemann sums, as explained in my comment above. Therefore $\int _0 ^1 1 \ \Bbb d x = 1$, no matter the distance on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AlexM.: You are wrong, just read my answer in detail.

Comment: If $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = 1$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ and $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n$ a system of intermediate points, then $\sum _{i=0} ^n 1 (\xi_i) (x_i - x_{i-1}) = \sum _{i=0} ^n (x_i - x_{i-1}) = x_n -x_0 = 1$, no matter what you say. (I am talking about the first lines of your answer.)

Comment: @AlexM.: It depends on how you define the Riemann integral with respect to a metric $\rho$ on $[a,b]$ and the standard metric on the target space. The natural thing to do is to consider $\sum_i f(\xi_i)\rho(x_{i-1}, x_i)$ (using areas of rectangles with respect to the new metric), this is what I had in mind.